# the first jquery code is not working.....is it because of jQuery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

Between these two jQuerys which i have written the second one is not working.

I suppose it is the case of jQuery conflict.

Please help....

```
<script>
 //this is the first jQuery code

  jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.rm option').each(function(){
      if($(this).text()==$('div#disp').text())
          $(this).attr('selected','selected');
                });
            });

//this is the second jQuery code
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 800
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 500
  }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });    $(function () { $('#dialog').dialog({       keyboard: true    })});
  </script>
```

Comment: Why are you writing a ready event handler that sets up a ready event handler that sets up a ready event handler?

Comment: `jQuery( document ).ready(function(){` === `$(function() {`

Comment: omit the first line....

still it is not working... i added that line cause someone told me it can resolve the issue.

Comment: jQuery( document ).ready equal $(document).ready, cos '$' equal 'jQuery' .

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in addition to the fact you have multiple ready handlers? Just by looking at it, it looks like you've opened up a number of brackets that haven't been closed, though I could be wrong due to the nature of the formating

Comment: no i am not confronting any javascript errors...

Comment: what is exactly not working as expected? dialog is not initialized? or dialog is not opened? or?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>

  $(document).ready(function(){

      $.each($('.rm option'), function( index, value ) {
        if( $(this).text() == $('div#disp').text() ){
          $(this).attr('selected','selected');
        }
      });

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 800
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 500
      },
    keyboard: true    
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });


  });
</script>
```

i fix unessesary '}' and remove useless .ready and functions, and also change .each to $.each

ps. edited, sorry, try now.